# Schema specified is not valid. Error

Tags: asp.net

[enter link description here](http://s20.postimg.org/f9xdevxb1/Errors.jpg)

As per picture mentioned error(click the link in above) during access Entity Framework tables in data source. I've built the Microsoft.AspNet.Providers -version 1.2 with using EntityFramework 5.0 from nuget console and try insert tables "Application,Role,User,Profile,Memebership" along with their inter relationship linking in keys. I've done with rebuild but still same error.

Could someone else who already know how to fix the problem and guide me to fixit in ASAP.

Comment: Did you try deleting all the existing entity tables and then  add

Comment: Dear cold, you are right. I try to not include table "Application" into my edmx and it is fined now. Why the "Applications" Tables had such problem when include into entityframe work model tables?